# Schema.org Event does not appear in Google Search

Tags: google-search-console, analytics-events

This is my Event Website:http://whittierevents.com/

I have added the Json schema on the site in order to show events in google search.
Crawled successfully on google webmaster too without any error.But events doesn't appear in google search on top
[image]

But when I search keyword "Whittier Events" on google, it doesn't show my events on top:
[image]

[image]

How this can be fixed?

Comment: Sorry but Rich Snippets can fail to display for a vast number of reasons, we have many generic questions regarding why  they may not display on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: But how this can be fixed then? How would I understand what's going wrong

Comment: You suppose use the rich snippet testing tool, you have some unrelanted errors but also you're displaying events that are not actually on the page... https://www.whittierevents.com/events/27th-annual-holiday-sonata/ for example has 38 events listed under Schema, and yet you don't have 37 of them on the page. Rich Snippets work on trust, if Google things something is fishy, it won't display them, fix your issues. Should also note, Google hates using rich snippets on homepages.